# Refined diffusion/heat models

Tags: thermodynamics, mathematical-physics

I'm a math student myself, but as is natural I encounter some physics along the way too. My question concerns the heat/diffusion model. As the reader will recall this is that the heat function $u(x,t):\Omega\times\Bbb [0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R$ solves the PDE $$u_t-D\Delta u = 0$$
subject to initial and boundary conditions. I will explain the reason for my concern in 1D to make the notation easier. An example of a system would be: $$\begin{cases}u_t-u_{xx} = 0, & (x,t)\in (0,L)\times(0,+\infty) \\ u(0,t) =u(L,t) = d, & t> 0 \\ u(x,0) = g(x), &x\in(0,L)\end{cases}$$

Now of course many other systems can be modeled; using variable boundary conditions, allowing sources/sinks to exist inside the domain, etc. The problem is that none of these modifications do anything to change this fact: if the sources/sinks, initial and boundary conditions are square integrable (this is *very* weak, a humongous range of horribly pathological creatures are square integrable), then $$u\in\mathcal C^\infty([0,L]\times(0,+\infty))$$

In other words, if I flick a light then the heat in the entire room (no matter how big) is *instantaneously* affected; it *has* to smooth out to meet the new condition *at once*.

No doubt this is preposterous, but I haven't been able to find (online) any modifications to the model that account for transition states. Can anyone share their knowledge here?

Comment: You are simply looking at the kiddie version of thermodynamic transport theory. However, if you think that the adult version is any better behaved, think again. It only gets MUCH worse from here.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm not sure what you mean by better behaved. Surely this one is *too* well behaved, and we want more realistic models to be "worse" behaved?

Comment: You know, as much as I've seen it claimed about instantaneous heat transport, none of my numerical simulations of the heat equation have ever shown this to be the case.

Comment: @KyleKanos that can depend on the numerical method used. For example, an explicit finite difference/volume scheme will not show instant transport of information, but an implicit scheme will.

Comment: @user3823992: Implicit methods allow you to have an arbitrarily *large* $dt$. However, we're talking about an arbitrarily **small** $dt$. Set it to machine precision & watch how the heat *doesn't* propagate the whole length ($L>0$) in just *one* timestep, regardless of method. And *that* is what I'm talking about here; the temperature does *not* change across the *whole* length of the rod ($L>0$), only across a *small* portion.

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm completely ignorant in numerical methods, but regardless, there's no doubting the proof that $u$ is smooth for *any* strictly positive $t$.

Comment: @KyleKanos, not sure if we're talking about the same thing then. An implicit formulation, regardless of time step, should indicate change across the domain in the first step. The amount of change in some places may be tiny and disappear due to machine error. The same is true in the analytic solutions, the entire domain begins changing immediately, but the rate of change can be extremely small far from the boundaries/heat sources.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed of heat / quantification of heat and other magnitudes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/179098/)